# How to make Xamarin program automatically reopen

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

How can I enable the application to open automatically when the device is restarted with the broadcast receiver?`Broadcastreceiver'd works when I print a message with this code. But when I redirect to mainActivity, that part does not work. How can I make the program trigger every time the device restarts?My code is as follows.

```
      public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
 {
     if (intent.Action == Intent.ActionBootCompleted)
     {
         Toast.MakeText(context, text: "Boot Completed", ToastLength.Short).Show();
         var foreGroundServiceIntent = new Intent(Application.Context, typeof(ForegroundService));
         foreGroundServiceIntent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
         foreGroundServiceIntent.AddCategory(Intent.CategoryDefault);
         Application.Context.StartForegroundService(intent);
         context.StartForegroundService(foreGroundServiceIntent);
     }
 }
```

Comment: Please format your code properly.

Comment: Have you added the ```RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED``` permission in AndroidManifest.xml ?

Comment: Yes. I added the RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED permission in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: What's the Android version do you use?